# Solve ODE by using Fourier Transform

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

$$- u''(x)+u(x)=f(x)$$

for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ with $\lim_{|x| \to \infty}u(x)=0, \lim_{|x| \to \infty}u'(x)=0$ and $f \in  L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^2(\mathbb{R})$. I need to solve this by using Fourier Transform.

It becomes more complicated since f(x) it is not defined but u(x) has to fulfill above conditions.

Can somebody solve this or give more than a short hint?

Comment: The conditions at $\pm\infty$ allow you to Fourier transform, integrate by parts twice to eliminate $u''$, trading it for $u$, and obtain $(s^2+1)\hat{u}(s)=\hat{f}(s)$.

Comment: The hint is to write down the Fourier transformed equations. The equation is algebraic and can be solved easily. The conditions on $u$ you will have to think a bit but the solution will show you the way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $U(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty u(x)e^{ikx}\,dx$ be the Fourier Transform of $u$ and let $F(k)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)e^{ikx}\,dx$ be the Fourier Transform of $f$.

Then, integrating by parts twice and using $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}u(x)=0$ and $\lim_{|x|\to \infty}u'(x)=0$ reveals

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty u''(x)e^{ikx}\,dx=-k^2U(k)$$

Therefore, the ODE for $u$ transforms to the equation

$$U(k)=\frac{F(k)}{k^2+1} \tag 1$$

Taking the inverse Fourier Transform of $(1)$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
u(x)&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{k^2+1}F(k)\,dk\\\\
&=\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ikx}}{k^2+1}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')e^{ikx'}\,dx'\,dk\\\\
&=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')\left(\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ik(x-x')}}{k^2+1}\,dk\right)\,dx' \tag 2
\end{align}$$

The inner integral on the right-hand side of $(2)$ can be evaluated using the residue theorem with the result

$$\frac1{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-ik(x-x')}}{k^2+1}\,dk=
\frac12e^{-|x-x'|}$$

Finally, the solution to the ODE is given by

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{u(x)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x')\frac{e^{-|x-x'|}}{2}\,dx'}$$